# How to write bytes to file from Python shell?

Tags: python

I have tried this
key

```
b"\xa9Z\xfe\x16*L\xfaJ\xab\x87\xc3\xdf$:f\xb3U^\xf4Nf\xe8\xc2\x1cZ\xc1\xd8\xdc\xe4h\x98\xac\xa3b\x98\xbc\x9e\xb5\xa8\x8d\xf7n\x1b\xa6\xbfMe\xa4\xd8\xc0\xd9'\x10\x86L?\xd3\xd4\xbd\xc2H\xaa\xe7\x07"
```

Open file in wb mode

```
>>> f = open('privkey.bin', 'wb' )
>>> f.write(key)
64
```

Any way the file is empty.
Why?

Comment: Did you close the file?

Comment: No,Yes now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close file first
`f.close()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `f.close()` the file to flush it to disk.

Alternatively, use the following to close it automatically:

```
>>> with open('privkey.bin', 'wb') as f:
>>>    f.write(key)
```